What is the mechanism of downgrade app in Android?
Can you tell me what is the mechanism of version downgrade in Android?
Let's assume that a new version of an application is rolled out and the production team crashes (yes, someone in the chain up to the production team obviously screwed up). The fix may take a long time and the quickest solution seems to be to roll back the application. It is important to note that inside the application package folder there are files necessary for work and a database file. Is it possible to make it so that at rollback these files were saved and how to be if there were serious changes in the database (for example, deletion of fields) (migration itself was described, but is it possible to restore the value of deleted fields?) Or is it not reasonable to roll back versions and only a quick fix will help?
We don`t use Google Console. Install from APK

There is no such mechanism, migrations are one-way. You'll have to find another way... even if one can rollback the release, you might end up with different versions of the database, which then need to be considered in future migrations.
I'd suggest to publish the next version, which skips the one faulty migration and instead fixes what can be fixed in the next migration; the values will be gone in every case and can only be reconstructed (depends what the fields contained).
You have to consider these two scenarios:

user ran the faulty migration -> fields need to be added again and filled, if possible.
user did not run the faulty migration -> the faulty migration needs to do nothing.

Like this you can at least prevent some damage, possibly not all the damage.
Also, take the faulty package offline, to prevent people from installing it.
